# compare the first index of sublists(within a list of lists) and then converting it to a set and back

Tags: python, set, nested-lists

I have a list of lists.  I want to collect all of the sublists with the same first element, combine their elements, and remove duplicates.  I'm getting close, but my current solution dies on an index error.

Current output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9], [5, 5, 8], [2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Correct output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 3, 2], [5, 5, 8], [2, 2, 0]] (not necessarily in that order)
```

Code:

```
listoflist = [[1,2,3,1],[4,5,6],[1,7,8],[4,3,2],[5,5,8],[2,2,0],[1,9,9]]

try: #(try and except is to deal with when lists are removed)
    for i in range(len(listoflist)): #iterating forwards
        x = listoflist[i][0] #indexing through sublists and setting the first value
        for j in range(len(listoflist)-1,0,-1): #iterating backwards
            if x == listoflist[j][0] and listoflist[i] != listoflist[j]: #comparing
                listoflist[i].extend(listoflist[j]) #combining lists and removing the old list
                listoflist.remove(listoflist[j]) 
                new = set(listoflist[i]) #conversion to set and back to list
                listoflist[i] = list()
                for obj in new:
                    listoflist[i].append(obj)
                    print listoflist[i]
    print listoflist


except IndexError:
    print listoflist
```

Comment: What's the expected output like?

Comment: For the listoflist I want it to be: [[1,2,3,7,8,9],[4,5,6,3,2],[5,5,8],[2,2,0]], (not necessarily in that order, just the combined lists that has duplicated values removed)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune Sorry about that. I am not sure at all how to minimize the code, but I tried to make it easier to read through.

Comment: should `[5, 5, 8], [2, 2, 0]` be `[5, 8], [2,  0]` since you say you are looking for a set?

Comment: Should be [5,8], [2,0] but I figured that part was simple to get afterwards - just wanted to make sure I got the main problem down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANALYSIS**

Your main problem is that you violate a basic practice: do *not* change an iterable while you're iterating on it.  Your outer loop runs `i` through values 0-5.  However, by the time you get to 4, you no longer have an item #4 in the list.  I did some simple tracing on your code, including a better message on error:

```
except IndexError:
    print "ERROR", i, j, listoflist
```

Output:

```
ERROR 4 1 [[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 9, 9, 1, 7, 8], [4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [5, 5, 8], [2, 2, 0]]
```

**REPAIR**

Don't alter the original list.  Instead, build a new list from the old one.  Gather all of the lists that begin with the same element; append the resulting set to the result you want.

```
listoflist = [[1,2,3,1],[4,5,6],[1,7,8],[4,3,2],[5,5,8],[2,2,0],[1,9,9]]
result = []

try:
    for i in range(len(listoflist)):
        x = listoflist[i][0]
        if x < 0:                       # Skip any sub-list already used
            continue

        gather = listoflist[i][:]       # Copy list for processing
        for j in range(len(listoflist)-1,0,-1):
            if x == listoflist[j][0] and i != j:
                gather.extend(listoflist[j])
                listoflist[j][0] = -j   # Uniquely mark this as not in use.
                print i, j, gather

        result.append(list(set(gather)))
        print i, result

    print result


except IndexError:
    print "ERROR", i, j, listoflist
```

Yes, this is still much longer than needed; if you really want to dig into Python, you can group the lists by first element and do all the processing in one long line.  I've tried to keep this more accessible for you.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification and help. That code is way cleaner and manageable. I appreciate your advice on how I should look to format things in the future as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I went for building `dict{}` based on the first elem in the list as the key, and merging the lists based on that.

```
listoflist = [[1,2,3,1],[4,5,6],[1,7,8],[4,3,2],[5,5,8],[2,2,0],[1,9,9]]
temp_dict = {}
result_list = []

# build a dict{int:list[]} based on first elem of list
for ll in listoflist:
  if ll[0] not in temp_dict:
    temp_dict[ll[0]]=ll
  else:
    for x in ll:
      temp_dict[ll[0]].append(x)
# now build a list of list with our dict
for key, values in temp_dict.items():
  temp_list = []
  temp_list.append(key)
  for x in values:
    if x not in temp_list:
      temp_list.append(x)
  result_list.append(temp_list)

print(result_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 3, 2], [5, 8], [2, 0]]
```

Comment: That's a really interesting solution, thanks for your help! I didn't even consider using a dictionary in this way.